# How to reduce lag in fabric.js recursion-based function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, fabricjs, lag

I am animating boxes using fabric.js to appear (canvas.add) onscreen as though they are being stitched on (see image).

[image: Embroidered Zigzags]

Due to the nature of the thing, I've implemented a recurring function with a timer.  As it runs, the more it starts to lag. I'd like to know if there's a way to reduce the lag.  It's especially bad at wide screen sizes (I'm able to get ~1880px) but unfortunately the design I'm working with has this element full-width (not just content).

I've included the recurring function below, but it's not much good without the rest, so check out the Fiddle. Please forgive the implementation - I got a stack overflow (hah) error from nesting groups too many times, hence the kludge-y group/item/counter traversal with a single array.

-- Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cesizemore/8xc89e4f/) --

I suspect it may be the sheer capacity of the objects rendering onscreen, as the lag is noticeably reduced by running just one line at a time (instead of all 3), but I just want to wipe across once and move on with the animation from there (sliding in stock images, text, CTA, etc.).  Can anybody suggest a better solution?  Most noticeable at larger screen sizes - I've left instructions in the Fiddle to test.

```
function embroider(obj,i){

    var iOffset = Math.floor(i/perLine);

    for(whichZigzag=0;whichZigzag<numZigzags;whichZigzag++){
        var whichGroup = (iOffset+(whichZigzag*numLines));
        var whichStitch = (i-(iOffset*perLine));
        for(four=0;four<4;four++, whichStitch++){
            canvas.add(obj[whichGroup].item(whichStitch));
        }
    }

    i+=4;

    if(i<perZigzag){
        setTimeout(function(){ // dont trigger immediately
            embroider(obj,i);
        },100);
    }
}
```

I'm mostly a lurker, so please let me know if my question and/or Fiddle suck and I'll try to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current lag is because each time you add an object to the canvas, it is re-rendered to display that object.

There is a property `renderOnAddRemove` which you can set to `false` for the Canvas. This will disable the automatic re-rendering that happens after each `canvas.add()`. You can then call `canvas.renderAll()` after the for loop, once all your objects are added.

Here is what [Documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#renderOnAddRemove) says about this property:

> Indicates whether fabric.Collection.add, fabric.Collection.insertAt and fabric.Collection.remove should also re-render canvas. Disabling this option could give a great performance boost when adding/removing a lot of objects to/from canvas at once (followed by a manual rendering after addition/deletion)

I have edited your fiddle. You can check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/4srj2sc8/3/

Comment: That looks *great* so far, thank you.  I have found that Fabric has very in-depth documentation but is very technical and the demos are too complicated for beginners.  I will leave this open for a short time to see if anyone else has any input, but I expect to mark this as correct.

Before I saw this, I started wondering whether [caching](http://fabricjs.com/svg-caching/) might help any...

Comment: Caching helps in cases where lot of low level command intensive svg images are rendered on the canvas. I don't think it will help in your case since what you are rendering are fabric rects.